# Make REST API call from C without using libcurl

Tags: c, rest, api, libcurl, cortex-m

I was trying to make REST calls from C; came across libcurl which was successful in doing that dynamically. But the code needs to be ported on to a Cortex M0 board, which need a lower footprint. Is there any workaround? All I need is to make a REST API call from C without any external library or overhead.

Comment: What are the specification of the REST api? as it covers a lot of definitions ( do you need to POST/PUT/DELETE or only GET), what is the expected answer form the REST endoint ( json/xml/plain text, even if that part is not covered by libCUrl ). If you are only using GET http verbs that could simplify things,

Comment: @dvhh Only requirement is a POST, and the answer format is not much of a concern at this point.

Comment: one option is to manually handle the HTTP protocol and read/write from/to a socket. an other option is to rebuild `libcurl` and trim everything you might not need at `configure` time.

Answer (score 7):

Well, how low do you want to go?

C doesn't know anything about REST, it doesn't know HTTP, not even TCP or something like a network interface. On bare metal, you'd start by reading the hardware specs of your network interface card and programming it (through ports, memory mapped registers, etc....) -- You'd have to understand ARP, IP, ICMP etc (and, of course, implement it), just to get a TCP connection on top of that.

Assuming there's an operating system in place, you'll be given some API, then the answer would depend on what this API allows. A typical level would be a "socket abstraction", like BSD sockets, which gives you functionality to establish a TCP connection. So, "all" you'd have to do is implement a HTTP client on top of that.

Unfortunately, HTTP itself is a complex protocol. You'd have to implement all the requests you need, with Content-Types, transfer encodings, etc and also handle all possible server responses appropriately. These are **a lot**. Bring content negotiation to the table, partial responses, etc ... it's "endless" work. That's exactly the reason there are libraries like curl that already implement all of this for you.

So, sorry to say that, but there's no simple answer possible giving you what you want here. If you want to get the job done, use a library. Maybe you can find something smaller than libcurl.

What you **can** do is to compile the library yourself, linking it statically and using compiler options like `gcc`'s `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and the linker option `--gc-sections` in an attempt to drop code from the library you don't use, this **might** help to reduce size.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; will give a try and drop out unused codes. Do you happen to know any other libraries with lesser size that will get the job done?

Comment: @Bhanz [This one is mine](https://github.com/iharob/libhttpio). It works pretty well and is self contained. Of course it could be improved a lot, but right now I don't have the time. BTW: It needs *openssl* but you can try to compile it without it too, it will not be hard I guess.

Comment: @Bhanz If you need any help feel free to communicate it to ihaorb@gmail.com.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Thanks a lot man. I will try and get back.